# Question about absolute value semantics and approach

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

A question of approach.. really basic I am afraid.

Given $$|a|\leq M$$
is this the correct approach?

$$\left| a \right| \leq M = \begin{cases}
 a \leq M, & a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a \leq M, & a \leq 0 
\end{cases}$$

$$ \qquad =  \begin{cases}
 a \leq M, & a \geq 0 \\ 
 a \geq -M, & a \leq 0 
\end{cases} $$

thus $$-M \leq a \leq M$$

Thanks.

Comment: Besides the strange use of the $=$ sign, it looks fine to me. Though you could change the intervals so that they don't both include zero.

Comment: @JamesA Could you elucidate. Part of the reason for the question is to learn how to write these things down correctly.

Comment: "Implies" ($\implies$) or "if and only if" ($\iff$) would be more suitable. I would write it as: $$\left| a \right| \leq M \iff \begin{cases}
 a \leq M, \qquad a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a \leq M, \qquad a< 0 
\end{cases}$$ since you're writing $|a|\leq M = a\leq M$ for $a\geq0$; it's *understandable* but I don't think it's correct.

Comment: @JamesA. Ah…I see what you mean. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic/reasoning is correct; the notation can be improved.

The use of the "$=$" sign is a bit problematic; these are equivalent statements, but we usually use another symbol, $\iff$ (if and only if, or "iff"), to denote equivalent statements.

As for the intervals for $a$, it would be cleaner if they were separate from eachother, as they currently both have $0$ ($a\leq0$ and $a\geq0$). Instead, you should include zero in only one of them.

Applying all this would result in your approach being written as:
$$\left| a \right| \leq M \iff \begin{cases}  a \leq M, & a \geq 0 \\ -a \leq M, & a< 0  \end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
 a \leq M, & a \geq 0 \\ 
 a \geq -M, & a < 0 
\end{cases}$$
thus $-M\leq a \leq M$.

Comment: Thank you....I really like the "cleaness" of your suggestion about the use of $<$.  So, quick point to clarify the other issue in my own mind. We could say, for example, $$\left| z \right| = \begin{cases}
 z, \qquad z \geq 0 \\ 
 -z, \qquad z < 0 
\end{cases}$$  ?  Your issue is that $|a| \leq M$ is a statement that can stand on it's own?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It might take a bit to get used to, but after reading a bit it will come naturally. Also, see the MathJax in my answer; use ```&``` instead of ```\quad``` for the cases, it aligns the intervals.

Comment: Thank you again. I am trying to go through Spivak, and I do find that unless you nail down these very elementary notions, it becomes less enjoyable and more of a grind. I will look at the MathJax and try and improve my use.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Also, [this](https://smccd.instructure.com/courses/27538/pages/the-difference-between-equals-=-and-implies-==%3E) might be useful.

Comment: Not sure how to do the "thank you very much" emoji, but you have really helped and it is appreciated. :-)